# Callback design pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, callback

Right now I have a client that sends a list of commands to my server that it wants data about.    My server loads these commands via a DLL using getProcAddress, for example:

```
InitializeDLL initializeDLL = (InitializeDLL)GetProcAddress(hInstanceLibrary, "InitializeDLL");
```

where initiailizeDLL is defined as:

```
typedef int (CALLBACK* InitializeDLL)(int,int);
```

The client right now sends the command name as a string for which it wants data for.  I have quite a list of commands that I would like to be able to use, and I don't have an idea on how to implement this in an efficient manner.  I was thinking of creating a Map and using the string for the name as a key and then the CALLBACK* for the appropriate function as a pointer.  But then I would also have to cast it afterwards.  I'm mostly a Java programmer, and not the best C++ programmer, so I'm not sure if this Map idea will even work or how to handle the cast at the end.  Also, I looked at the Command pattern on Wikipedia, but don't know how that would be implemented in this case.

Comment: Using a `map<>` does not seem like a bad idea. Give it a go, and if you face problems, you can come back and ask different question. The nice thing about STL containers is that it is relatively painless to change one out for another, as long as you `typedef` the container.

Comment: Will all the function pointers have the same singature?

Comment: Most function pointers are similar, although a couple return double instead of int and the number of parameters can vary.

Answer (score 0):

A map should be fine to do this. A map that maps each and every string to a function pointer that will execute when a certain message is received. If you want to go the command pattern then you can have something like :
Disclamer, I have not written C++ code since ages, this code might not compile):

```
abstract class Command{
  private:
     string commandName;
     CALLBACK* callBackFunction
  public:
     Command(string name, CALLBACK* function){
        commandName = name;
        callBackFunction = function;
     }
     // Here, you can check your current environment
     // to see if you can execute this command in the current
     // configuration and system state
     bool CanExecute() = 0;

     // This method does the call to the callback
     void Execute(){
          // call the callback function here
     }
}
```

This pattern is a mix of the command and factory method patterns. 
Define commands that inherit from the abstract class `Command` for every possible entry. Now, instead of having a map of strings with function pointers, you can have a map of strings with commands. When you get a string, call your command's `CanExecute` first to see if the command can be executed in the current state. Call `Execute` to run your command in which you call the callback function.
This is the best way I can think of encapsulating commands, their execution preconditions and their actual code to execute.

On a side note, this pattern is widely used now in .NET (WPF)